# Tkinter text with transparent background

Tags: python, tkinter, background, widget, transparent

my only question is how to make a transparent text in tkinter : any type of widget with transparent background is a good answer. 
I need this for apply the text on a picture. 
Thanks for any type of answer

Comment: You would need a text object on a canvas to do this. You could also place the picture on the canvas.

Comment: How do you make a text object on a canvas which is transparent?

Comment: It is automatically transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, for example you could have an png image with text(do this via a photo editor), you can use a canvas and draw on that, or you can use a disabled button with an image background with text.

**Canvas**:

```
c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack()
c.create_image(x, y, img)
c.create_text(x, y, "My Text")
```

**Button**:

```
img = PhotoImage(file="file.png")
b = tk.Button(root, text="My Text", image=img, relief="FLAT", state="DISABLED")
b.image = img
b.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks for this but why do I need to create a create_image before : Ive already my picture in the background...

Comment: If your already using Canvas then just add text to it. Text on the canvas with no fill will draw transparently.

Comment: I realy don't know how to do this... I need to place the text at `widget.place(relx=0.14, rely=0.58, height=30, width=100)`

Comment: Just do `c.create_text(widget.x*0.14, widget.y*0.58, "My Text")` where widget.x is the x of the widget in relation to the canvas and the y in the y of the widget in relation to the canvas.