# How to display TEXT ONLY (transparent background, with no menu bar or buttons) on screen using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pysimplegui, easygui

I have been looking everywhere for this kind of simple solution and I'm still coming up short.

All I want to do is simply splash some text only onto the screen, without a background or using a "message box" that has a menu bar/buttons with it. Just text, that's all. Maybe with a way to set a color for the font as well as I want the text to be a light gray. Using Windows 10 and Python 3.8+.

I've looked at easygui (message box, uses buttons), PySimpleGUI (best option so far, shown below, but defaults to a white background), Tkinter and pygame (but I have no clue how to set up what I'm looking for with those packages.

This is what I have using PySimpleGui, would love for this to be a transparent background if possible!

```
def popup_message(message):
    sg.popup(str(message),
                title = None,
                button_color = 'white',
                background_color = None,
                text_color = 'grey85',#'light gray',
                button_type = 5,
                auto_close = True,
                auto_close_duration = 20,
                custom_text = (None, None),
                non_blocking = False,
                icon = None,
                line_width = None,
                font = None,
                no_titlebar = True,
                grab_anywhere = True,
                keep_on_top = True,
                location = (None, None),
                relative_location = (250, 250),
                any_key_closes = True,
                image = None,
                modal = True)
```

**UPDATE**

This is the closest thing I've got with using Tkinter. Problem now is the menu bar is still visible, and using the Label class results in a solid background. HOW CAN I ONLY SHOW TEXT ON SCREEN IN PYTHON!? I'm not even sure I'm going about this the right way, but seems like a pretty basic idea?

```
# Import the Tkinter Library
from tkinter import *

# Create an instance of Tkinter Frame
root = Tk()

# Create a Label to print some text
label = Label(root, text="This is a New Line Text", font= ('Helvetica 14 bold'), foreground= "red3")
label.pack()

# Create a transparent window
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','#add123')

# Set the geometry of window
root.geometry("700x350")

# Add a background color to the Main Window
root.config(bg = '#add123')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: No you cannot make the window transparent using `popup()`.

Comment: That's what I figured, but looking for the best solution to my problem. Hard to believe there isn't a simple way to print text only onto the screen with Python...

Comment: You need to set the background color of the label to `#add123` as well in your updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent background of `Text` in `popup`is not supported.

New popup function required and defined by yourself in PySimpleGUI.

- Set option `background_color` of your `Text` element to one specified color for transparency, like '#add123'.
- Set option `transparent_color` in `Window` to the specified color for transparency.
- Set option `no_titlebar` in `Window` to hide the titlebar.

Following code show the way

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(message):
    global win
    if win:
        win.close()
    layout = [[sg.Text(message, background_color=bg, pad=(0, 0))]]
    win = sg.Window('title', layout, no_titlebar=True, keep_on_top=True,
        location=(1000, 200), auto_close=True, auto_close_duration=3,
        transparent_color=bg, margins=(0, 0))
    event, values = win.read(timeout=0)
    return win

bg = '#add123'
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 24))
layout = [[sg.Button('POPUP')]]
window = sg.Window('title', layout)
win = None
while True:

    event, value = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'POPUP':
        win = popup('Here is the message.')
        window.force_focus()

if win:
    win.close()
window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: See my next question as I think you might be able to assist there too:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453039/pysimplegui-window-disappearing-too-quickly-some-other-options-needed

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a sort of screen without a `title-menu.` In, that case I can help you by telling you to use `root.overrideredirect(True)` which is a crucial part of your code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that as I don't use Tkinter at all, but see my update above as I tried to accomplish it using Tkinter, but of course there's issues with it too...

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for drawing text without a background.
The first is to use the canvas to draw the text as seen below. With this approach, you'd have to center the text yourself everytime the window is resized if you care about resizability.

```
canvas.create_text(x, y, "Text with no bg!")
```

Second approach is to use a disabled button with an empty img inside.

```
img = PhotoImage(file="file.png")
b = tk.Button(root, text="My Text", image=img, relief="FLAT", state="DISABLED")
b.image = img
b.pack()
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348539/tkinter-text-with-transparent-background) for more info.
Let me know if you have any other questions.