# PySimpleGUI Window Disappearing too Quickly/Some Other Options Needed

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I've created a PySimpleGUI Window with some text, a transparent background and no title bar, however it's not respecting the auto_close_duration property. I know it'll be because I'm not implementing it correctly, but just looking at how to fix that.

Also, I would like the window to stay alive for that amount of time before closing, but also to listen for any keyboard button press to auto close it early. If any keyboard button doesn't work, the Escape button could be used, but on ANY keyboard press is ideal.

This is what I have right now, it flashes the text before disappearing. Python 3.8+ Windows 10.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(message):

    # Set font options
    sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 24))

    # Define the transparent bg colour
    bg = '#add123'

    # Define a layout with our message to display
    layout = [[sg.Text(message, background_color=bg, pad=(0, 0))]]

    # Get the width and height of the current monitor (to use later)
    w, h = sg.Window.get_screen_size()

    # Define a window object to show our layout
    win = sg.Window('title', layout,
                    no_titlebar=True,
                    keep_on_top=True,
                    location=(None, None),
                    auto_close=True,
                    auto_close_duration=20,
                    transparent_color=bg,
                    margins=(0, 0),
                    # finalize=True,
                    )

    # Read the window?
    event, values = win.read(timeout=0)

    # Attempts to keep window alive for the auto_close_duration
    win.force_focus()

    # 1. How to keep window/popup message visible for auto_close_duration?
    # 2. How to close window if ANY keyboard button pressed, or the Escape key at the least?

    # win.close()
    return

popup('Here is the message.')
```

Comment: In you code, this popup is a non-blocked popup window, so after statement `popup('Here is the message.')`, your script end, then popup window also closed before auto closed, so we need a main window to keep script running under event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set two conditions to generate keyboard event to exit.

- option `return_keyboard_events=True` in `Window` and
- option `timeout` in method `read` of `Window`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(message):
    sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 24))
    bg = '#add123'
    layout = [[sg.Text(message, background_color=bg, pad=(0, 0))]]
    win = sg.Window('title', layout, no_titlebar=True, keep_on_top=True,
        location=(1000, 200), transparent_color=bg, margins=(0, 0),
        return_keyboard_events=True)
    win.read(timeout=3000, close=True)
    return

popup('Here is the message.')
```

Comment: But how do I get rid of the "main" window with the popup button? I don't want a button to be displayed at all, I just want the text to pop up by itself, stay visible for a few seconds, and then disappear either on its own, or by keyboard button press?

Comment: I mixed this question with another one, update as above.